# How to avoid PhpStorm staging file on Refactor > Rename

Tags: git, file, phpstorm, rename

When creating a file under PhpStorm, it appears untracked in Git. 
But using Refactor > Rename, it moves the file to the staged area.

Is there any way to disable this ?

Comment: Why should you create new files and then refactor them before commit? What's your goal? You can unstage files manually if you want

Comment: Yeah, the whole process is Create a file > put stuff in or some work around > rename the file because its purpose is much clear now... It does not matter much, but I usually don't like when things gets "magic". Please IDE, don't do anything that I've not asked for :)

Comment: It's not only about new files. It also happens when renaming or moving existing files. It's very much unwanted behavior for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is related to [this thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206999045-PhpStorm-with-git-automatically-adds-stages-removed-and-moved-files):

> What settings are chosen in Settings | Version Control | Confirmation?
>   Do you have 'Add silently' and 'Remove silently' enabled?
>
> With those settings, I can prevent WebStorm from automatically staging changed, added or deleted files in git.
>
> **Moved or renamed files are still automatically staged, though.**

If that is still the case, you need to vote for [issue **IDEA-165445**](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165445).